# Haskell Netwire - Type errors

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frp, netwire

I have just started using netwire and I'm having trouble with the very basics.

The following code works fine for me:

```
main :: IO ()
main = testWire clockSession_ (for 3 . yeah)

yeah :: Monad m => Wire s () m a String
yeah = pure "yes"
```

But this does not:

```
main :: IO ()
main = testWire clockSession_ forYeah

forYeah :: (Show b, Show e) => Wire s e Identity a b
forYeah = for 3 . yeah
```

fails with error:

```
Could not deduce (b ~ [Char])
from the context (Show b, Show e)
bound by the type signature for
forYeah :: (Show b, Show e) => Wire s e Identity a b
  at /home/fiendfan1/workspace/Haskell/Haskell-OpenGL/src/Main.hs:12:12-54
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        forYeah :: (Show b, Show e) => Wire s e Identity a b
      at /home/fiendfan1/workspace/Haskell/Haskell-OpenGL/src/Main.hs:12:12
Expected type: Wire s e Identity a b
  Actual type: Wire s () Identity a String
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `yeah'
In the expression: for 3 . yeah
In an equation for `forYeah': forYeah = for 3 . yeah
```

So I changed it to:

```
forYeah :: Show e => Wire s e Identity a String
```

which gives me the error:

```
Could not deduce (e ~ ())
from the context (Show e)
  bound by the type signature for
             forYeah :: Show e => Wire s e Identity a String
  at /home/fiendfan1/workspace/Haskell/Haskell-OpenGL/src/Main.hs:12:12-49
  `e' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        forYeah :: Show e => Wire s e Identity a String
      at /home/fiendfan1/workspace/Haskell/Haskell-OpenGL/src/Main.hs:12:12
Expected type: Wire s e Identity a String
  Actual type: Wire s () Identity a String
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `yeah'
In the expression: for 3 . yeah
In an equation for `forYeah': forYeah = for 3 . yeah
```

Changing it to:

```
forYeah :: Wire s () Identity a String
```

Gives the following error:

```
No instance for (HasTime Integer s) arising from a use of `for'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (HasTime Integer s)
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `for 3'
In the expression: for 3 . yeah
In an equation for `forYeah': forYeah = for 3 . yeah
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how I can fix my second code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Here's a complete, compiling, running solution to this problem:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import qualified Prelude as Prelude
import Control.Wire
import Control.Wire.Interval

main :: IO ()
main = testWire clockSession_ (withoutErrors forYeah)

yeah :: Monad m => Wire s e m a String
yeah = pure "yes"

forYeah :: (Num t, HasTime t s, Monoid e, Monad m) => Wire s e m a String
forYeah = for 3 . yeah

-- This just is an easy way to specify to use () as the type for errors in testWire
withoutErrors :: Wire s () m a b -> Wire s () m a b 
withoutErrors = Prelude.id
```

Here's the original answer, that discussed why we should change the type of `yeah`, and then the necessary changes to the type of `forYeah`:

Change the type of `yeah` to `Monad m => Wire s e m a String`. `Monad m => (Wire s e m a)` has an `Applicative` instance , so `pure` should exist without specifying that the second type argument to `Wire` in `yeah`'s type is `()`.

Note: I don't use netwire and I haven't tried compiling this. I've only looked at the types in the documentation.

**Edit:** You probably also need to change the type of `forYeah`.

`Wire` also has a `Category` instance:

```
Monad m => Category (Wire s e m)
```

`Category`'s `.` operator has the following type:

```
(.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

So for `Wire`s it is:

```
(.) :: Monad m => Wire s e m b c -> Wire s e m a b -> Wire s e m a c
```

`for` has the following type:

```
for :: (HasTime t s, Monoid e) => t -> Wire s e m a a
```

So `for 3` would have a type like `(HasTime Int s, Monoid e) => Wire s e m a a`. Combined with yeah's type of `Monad m => Wire s e m a String`, `for 3 . yeah` would have a type like

```
(HasTime Int s, Monoid e, Monad m) => Wire s e m a String
```

So we could probably change the type of `forYeah` to:

```
forYeah :: (HasTime Int s, Monoid e, Monad m) => Wire s e m a String
```

**Edit:** Even better type for `forYeah`

Since [an integer numeral (without a decimal point) is actually equivalent to an application of fromInteger to the value of the numeral as an Integer](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html), and `fromInteger :: (Num a) => Integer -> a`, the literal `3` actually has type `Num t => t`. The best type we can choose is therefore probably:

```
forYeah :: (Num t, HasTime t s, Monoid e, Monad m) => Wire s e m a String
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I change the type of forYeah to

```
forYeah::Wire (Timed NominalDiffTime ()) () Identity a String
```

It also works if you leave out the type of forYeah.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked GHCi what the type was:

```
> :m Control.Wire
> :t for (3 :: Int) . pure "yes"
for 3 . pure "yes" :: (Monad m, HasTime Int s, Monoid e) => Wire s e m a [Char]
> :{
| let forYeah :: HasTime Int s => Wire s () Identity a String
|     forYeah = for 3 . pure "yes"
| :}
> :t forYeah
forYeah :: HasTime Int s => Wire s () Identity a String
```

So that works.  However, when asking the type of `testWire clockSession_ forYeah`, I get an error saying that it can't match `NominalDiffTime` with `Int`, but since `NominalDiffTime` is also an instance of `Num`, it's pretty easy to just change the signature:

```
> :{
| let forYeah :: HasTime NominalDiffTime s => Wire s () Identity a String
|     forYeah = for 3 . pure "yes"
| :}
> :t testWire clockSession_ forYeah
testWire clockSession_ forYeah :: (Applicative m, MonadIO m) => m c
```

So that seems like it'd work.

Also, it worked when I defined `yeah` separately as

```
yeah :: Monad m => Wire s () m a String
yeah = pure "yes"

forYeah :: HasTime t s => Wire s () Identity a String
forYeah = for 3 . yeah
```

The problem seemed to be in the `HasTime` constraint.  Since you had left it out, the compiler defaulted the literal `3` to the type `Integer`, but there is not an instance for `HasTime Integer s` for any `s`.